# Webview sending requests in Http instead of https

Tags: android, laravel-5

Webview is sending the below post request parameters in http while browser is sending it in https.

eventhough payment is getting success, the order is getting failed and redirected to failure page. Is there any way to force webview to handle all in https.

merchant_id: xxx@test.com

billing_fullname: S S

billing_address:  ,

billing_city:

billing_postcode:

email_address: s@yopmail.com

customer_phone_number: 91111111111

hide_billing_details: true

callback_url: **http://test.com/?&token=520f67a5cd475310fd154f73&action=process&key=1552723214&callback=1&userid=7406**

test_transaction: 100

test_success_url: http://test.com/?&token=520f67a5cd475310fd154f73&action=process&key=1552723214&text=1&success=1

test_cancel_url: http://test.com/?action=failed&key=1552723214&text=1

amount: 1